# Allowing underscore in the "id" datatype

Tags: hl7-fhir

As per the FHIR spec, the [id](https://www.hl7.org/fhir/datatypes.html#id) datatype supports the following characters -
'A'..'Z', and 'a'..'z', numerals ('0'..'9'), '-' and '.'

However, when generating FHIR responses from our SoR, we are creating the "id" value (resource.id) of some resources dynamically by using keywords/terminology used in the SoR and some of these keywords contain the '_' character. This results in the generated "id" value also containing '_' characters. Subsequent URL invocations or reference URLs to such resources have '_' characters in them (the "id" in the "..resource/{id}" snippet).

While [RFC3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) indicates that '_' are okay to be used in URLs, is there any reason that '_' is restricted from being used in "id" values in FHIR?

Answer (score 1):

There's not a deep connection between the characters we allow in FHIR IDs and the characters allowed in a URL -- except that FHIR's design ensures that FHIR IDs are always valid path segments.

One reason we omit `_` from the allowed characters in a FHIR ID is to avoid ambiguity in cases like:

```
GET /Patient/_search
```

... where http://hl7.org/fhir/http.html#search ensures that `_search` is a reserved word. By omitting `_` (and `$` for that matter) from valid FHIR IDs, we ensure that `_search` can never accidentally be parsed as a resource ID.

Comment: Thanks Josh. I understand what you mean, there a re several FHIR keywords (few in the path, but mostly in the query) that are prefixed with '\_'. And not using '\$' as they are prefixes for operations makes sense. 

I found the reference to the same [here](http://hl7.org/fhir/http.html#styleguide) - "This specification uses the underscore as a **prefix** to disambiguate reserved names from other names..."

Extending my question, would it make sense to allow `_` in ids but just not as prefixes - would this still allow the principle you highlighted to be honored?

Comment: At this point, doing so would be a breaking change to a normative part of the specification.  While theoretically possible, it's not something we'd push for without a very strong reason.  Given that implementers can easily convert underscores to dashes, which are allowed, it seems unlikely we'll see a strong reason.  That said, if you have a strong reason, you can propose a change using the "propose a change" link at the bottom of any page in the FHIR spec.

Comment: Thanks Lloyd. We did think of substitution as well, unfortunately the only two options - `-` is used as a delimiter in our ids and `.` is also present in SoR keywords. We will explore a change in implementation and initiate a proposal for change as well.

Comment: For those coming to this that are still confused, you are not alone. Name can have an underscore but not a dash; ID can have dash but not underscore. This means that there isn't a consistent way to break up long strings with a standard char as is parseable in all programming languages. If you use one you'll be penalized for the other data type. I'd be happy to learn if there's a consistent char to use to break up long strings in both Name and ID.